# Angular - dynamic module loading and compilation

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, webpack-2, systemjs

I am developing an Ionic 3 / Angular 4 app with cordova. we need to be able to create modules/components independently from the app to quickly change e.g. information pages. I have read this:

[Article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

specifically, I am trying to do what the author did under

> dynamic component loading and compilation

```
@ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) _container: ViewContainerRef;

System.import('http://localhost:8080/path/to/js/file.js').then((module) => {
        this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module.ExampleModule)
            .then((compiled) => {
                const factory = compiled.componentFactories[0];
                this._container.createComponent(factory);
            })
    })
```

This is working in in the example application found on [Github](https://github.com/maximusk/Here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-Angular).

But as far as I know ionic/angular uses webpack and I don't want to replace Webpack with SystemJS (if thats even possible). I just want to use the `System.import()` from SystemJS or a similar thing with Webpack. And i just don't know how to configure that.

Right now i am getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'http://localhost:8080/path/to/js/file.js'.
Error: Cannot find module 'http://localhost:8080/path/to/js/file.js'.
    at script-loader lazy:2
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at webpackEmptyAsyncContext (script-loader lazy:2)
    at ScriptLoaderProvider.webpackJsonp.333.ScriptLoaderProvider.loadScript (script-loader.ts:19)
    at FlexiPage.webpackJsonp.112.FlexiPage.ionViewDidLoad (flexi.ts:38)
    at ViewController._lifecycle (view-controller.js:566)
    at ViewController._didLoad (view-controller.js:439)
    at NavControllerBase._didLoad (nav-controller-base.js:950)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at script-loader lazy:2
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at webpackEmptyAsyncContext (script-loader lazy:2)
    at ScriptLoaderProvider.webpackJsonp.333.ScriptLoaderProvider.loadScript (script-loader.ts:19)
    at FlexiPage.webpackJsonp.112.FlexiPage.ionViewDidLoad (flexi.ts:38)
    at ViewController._lifecycle (view-controller.js:566)
    at ViewController._didLoad (view-controller.js:439)
    at NavControllerBase._didLoad (nav-controller-base.js:950)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at o (polyfills.js:3)
    at HTMLElement.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
```

It looks like it doesn't find the resource, but I think it is a misconfiguration with SystemJS, as it works in the sample app. Actually the first problem i am facing is, how to properly add SystemJS to the Ionic app.

If anyone has some insight, i would appreciate it very much.

Comment: what version of webpack are you using? if you use `v3`, you can use `import()` function if you know the module name **at the build time**. check [this thread](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3098). I used SystemJS because the module name was not known during build time and webpack can't load modules it doesn't know about during build time

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but this exactly how i need to implement it. The modules won't be known at build time. Maybe i should rather post a question into the ionic forum on how to add systemJS.

Comment: then you can't use webpack to load modules dynamically. you either have to use SystemJS or FuseBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular compiler is not included at runtime in AOT compilation (default for Ionic production builds), it's not a good idea to not use AOT for ionic as you want the app to be as fast as possible.